# Combinatorics with sequences

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a_n$ be the number of sequences of $n$ terms formed using only the digits $0,1,2$ and $3$ in which $0$ occurs an odd number of times. Find $a_n$.

I tried to solve this considering the cases for one zero, three zeroes and so on. But then I realized that $1,2$ and $3$ are not distinct.

Comment: Must the $0$ occur at all in any sequence? Is it possible that the $0$ need not occur? I know $0$ appearing "$0$ times" is not an  odd number of  times, but I'm just asking.

Comment: The same question occurred to me. But I would like a solution without considering that particular case.

Comment: By that, you mean that I *should not consider* the possibility of no zeros? So *there must be a zero in my sequence*?

Comment: Yes. Please do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we are given $n$. Fix the number of zeros in $n$, say $k$. Then, the position of these zeros must be fixed, this is done in $\binom{n}{k}$ ways. Now, the rest of the spots are filled by any one of $1,2,3$, this is done in $3^{n-k}$ ways.

Hence, the answer is $$
a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1,  k\ \textrm{odd}}^n \binom{n}{k} 3^{n-k}
$$

Now, we know that if $n$ is odd, then k will vary from $1$ to $n$ in steps of $2$, hence for odd $n$:
$$
a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k =0}^\frac{n-1}{2} \binom{n}{2k+1} 3^{n-2k-1}
$$
For even $n$, we don't include $n$ itself, so:
$$
a_n = \displaystyle\sum_{k =0}^\frac{n-2}{2} \binom{n}{2k+1} 3^{n-2k-1}
$$
Suppose we are including the fact that zeros need not occur at all in the sequence, then all we need to do is to add $3^n$ to each of the above terms, since this exactly accounts for that case.